how sort filter data with other columns in Apache Superset?
I have a dataset in Apache Superset that contain two columns order and name.
I want add this dataset to a dashboard filters that show the name of this dataset but it sort with order.
How can do this in Superset?
And if i a dataset that use jinja template for filtering with that filter and I want when user select a name, I use the order in where of my dataset for filtering how can I do that?

were you able to resolve this?
